Safe variables in a .dir-locals.el file
I created a .dir-locals.el file using M-x add-dir-local-variable. The resulting file looks like this:
;;; Directory Local Variables            -*- no-byte-compile: t -*-
;;; For more information see (info "(emacs) Directory Variables")

((nil . ((bibtex-completion-bibliography . ~/Dropbox/reading/books.bib))))

When I open books.bib the *Local Variables* buffer informs me that the variable bibtex-completion-bibliography may not be safe.
I understand that I can fix this by selecting either y or !, which adds safe-local-variable-values to my init.el. I would prefer not to do this, because I want to create .dir-locals.el files for several projects that I am working on.
I will admit that I don't fully understand the idea of 'safe' variables; if I assign a value to bibtex-completion-bibliography with a setq statement inside my init.el the variable is safe by default.
My question is: Is there something that I can add to the .dir-locals.el file to indicate that this variable is safe?

Quite apart from safety issues, note that the path name of your bibliography file should be a string (i.e. enclosed in double quotes: "~/Dropbox/reading/books.bib"). Otherwise, when you call a function that uses it, e.g. bibtex-completion-normalize-bibliography, you are going to get an error: Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp ~/Dropbox/reading/books.bib).

Oh good grief.  So annoyed I didn't notice that...

PhilC: surely that wasn't actually functional?!


I understand that I can fix this by selecting either y or !, which adds safe-local-variable-values to my init.el. I would prefer not to do this, because I want to create .dir-locals.el files for several projects that I am working on.

There's no issue with doing that -- Emacs can store any number of variable/value pairs as safe; so you can confirm the safeness of the selected bibtex-completion-bibliography for each of your projects without clobbering any previously-saved values for the others.

I will admit that I don't fully understand the idea of 'safe' variables
[...]
My question is: Is there something that I can add to the .dir-locals.el file to indicate that this variable is safe?

No, and the reason for that is the thing you weren't understanding about the idea of 'safe' variables...
File- and Directory-local variables may be 'unsafe' because (certainly so far as Emacs knows) those files and directories may be visited by any number of users.
If user A puts something malicious into the file/dir-local values and they were also able to put something into those same settings to say "don't worry -- I promise it's safe", then user B wouldn't be protected.
Which also explains...

if I assign a value to bibtex-completion-bibliography with a setq statement inside my init.el the variable is safe by default.

...because you are the only one using your init file (just as 'safe' values stored in your init file by the customize system will only be seen by you).

You do have another option.  Quoting from C-hig (elisp)File Local Variables:

You can specify safe values for a variable with a
‘safe-local-variable’ property.  The property has to be a function
of one argument; any value is safe if the function returns non-‘nil’
given that value.  Many commonly-encountered file variables have
‘safe-local-variable’ properties; these include ‘fill-column’,
‘fill-prefix’, and ‘indent-tabs-mode’.  For boolean-valued variables
that are safe, use ‘booleanp’ as the property value.

E.g.:
(defcustom my-safe-bibliography-files
  '("~/Dropbox/reading/books.bib"
    "~/Dropbox/reading/more-books.bib")
  "Safe file/dir-local values for `bibtex-completion-bibliography'."
  :type '(repeat file)
  :group 'bibtex)

(defun my-safe-bibliography-file-p (file)
  "Non-nil if FILE is a member of `my-safe-bibliography-files'."
  (member file my-safe-bibliography-files))

(put 'bibtex-completion-bibliography
     'safe-local-variable 'my-safe-bibliography-file-p)


The bibtex-completion.el library also includes this autoload cookie: ;;;###autoload (put 'bibtex-completion-bibliography 'safe-local-variable 'stringp), so assuming that the library is (auto)loaded early enough (and assuming that the OP fixes the dir-locals setting to be a string), that should be enough to avoid the safety warning - right?

Yes, if the OP has that same autoload in place, something else seems amiss (and presumably all filename strings are officially considered safe, so there should be no need to do any of this).

Thanks @phils for your detailed response. I'm the only user of my home computer, nonetheless, it's good to know what Emacs thinks. As recommended by @NickD, (thanks, @NickD) I have enclosed file names and paths in double quotes. The whole point of this exercise is to get helm-bibtex running. When I call up helm-bibtex I get the error message Wrong type argument, strings, ~/Dropbox/reading/books.bib.   Where is this coming from? @NickD, I know nothing about autoload cookies. Do I need to set something, or is this set by bibtex-completion.el?

@PhilC: Wrong type argument, stringp, ~/Dropbox/reading/books.bib (I'm assuming strings was a typo) shows that you're still trying to use a value which is not double-quoted.  stringp is a predicate function (this is what the p suffix means) which determines whether its argument is a string, so this error means that something which is not a string has been used in a context that requires one.  The error shows an unquoted value, so evidentially you're still using an unquoted ~/Dropbox/reading/books.bib somewhere.

If you use M-x toggle-debug-on-error you should get a backtrace when the error occurs.  If you can't figure it out, add the backtrack to your question.

@phils, thanks again for your comments. This latest error is a mistake of mine, somehow I got a second version of .dir-locals.el in my .emacs.d directory, which clobbered everything else. Sorry for wasting your time.helm-bibtex now works mostly as it should, but notes and pdf symbols don't appear. I checked these variables with C-h v, the variables are set correctly. Any ideas on why this might be happening?

None, sorry -- I'm afraid I don't know anything about helm or bibtex, let alone a combination of the two.
